# How do you display latitude \ longitude coordinates in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I would like to display latitude and longtitude coordinates (at the bottom of window) for my data which I am editing in different coordinate system. Is it possible?

Comment: See here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help./index.html#//00660000000v000000

Comment: @HimBromBeere you should elevate this to answer as it is the correction solution.

Comment: @Hornbydd Sure, but providing a link is not really an answer. Furthermore cl3 already did the job.

Comment: The glory snatched from your hands!

Comment: Hey, to be fair @HimBromBeere 's comment wasn't there when I started typing my answer. Otherwise I wouldn't have bothered. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Right click inside your data frame and open the "Properties" window. Go to the "General" tab. Under the "Units" sun-heading change the "Display" drop-down to whatever format you wish to use (DD or DMS in your case).

Look at "Working with Map Units" [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help./index.html#//00660000000v000000) if you need more help.